# add string to app maker dropdown menu options in addition to datasource items

Tags: dropdown, google-workspace, google-app-maker

I have a drop-down menu that i want to populate from one specific Datasource.
the issue is i want to add one option that isn't an item in the db.

The table I have is `Brand`.

The value of options for that dropdown currently is `@datasources.Brand.items`, which shows all the items in the db.

- Brand item 1
- Brand item 2
- Brand item 3

All the items in Brand will be in the dropdown , but i want to add one option "All Brands".

I tried to set options of the dropdown to ["All Brands",`@datasources.Brand.items`]

I don't get the result i want i get "All Brands as option 1 and the 2nd one is one line:

```
SimplePropertyList{itemType=Brand Record,items[com.google.apps.appmaker.client.model.ActiveRecord.
```

What I'm looking for is:

- All Brands
- Brand item 1
- Brand item 2
- ....

Comment: Depending on the query, can you use a UNION to add "All Brands"?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to allow null and use the null value for all brands.

Comment: @Jon but how to do the query to be able to use union in the options ?

Comment: @Morfinismo will try to keep that option as the last one , there must be a way , unfortunately i'm still new to all this and having a difficulty

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist in not using the `null` value and you must have the "All Brands" option as one of the selections, then you need to do the following on the options binding:

```
Array.prototype.concat(
    ["All Brands"], 
    (@datasources.Brand.items).map(function(item){return item.BRANDNAME;})
)
```

In the above, `BRANDNAME` represents the field name that contains the brand name in your model.

Please note that this approach will not allow you to choose a **brand** record from the dropdown, but instead it will only allow you to choose the brand name(which is a string).

If you are looking for an approach that will let you choose the record instead of only the brand name, then you will need to create a record that contains the "All Brands" as a name and then you can simply sort it to make sure it always appear at the top by doing the following on the binding:

```
(@datasources.Brand.items).sort(function(a,b){
    return a.BRANDNAME === "All Brands" ? -1 : 1;
});
```